# how to play audio from database on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

i want to play the audio on the basis of alphabet enter in textbox.
So when text is written in Textbox1, it should fetch the database with that particular word. So on button click the Literal1 get invoked which should play the audio.

```
protected void speakBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from tblfiles5 where voicename='" + TextBox1.Text + "'",con))
        {
            MySqlDataReader mdr;

            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();

            mdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (mdr.Read())
            {
                MessageBox.Show(TextBox1.Text);
                string link = "<audio controls> <Source src= "+ mdr.Read() + " type =audio/wav ></audio>";
                Literal1.Text = link;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No "+ TextBox1.Text+" exist in database");
            }
                con.Close();
        }
    }
    Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
}
```

**Below is my o/p screenshot**

[image: Click to browse image]

Comment: Above all else, **read up on [SQL injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)** because you are vulnerable to it.

Comment: Calling `MessageBox.Show` in a server environment will _not_ work as expected.

Comment: MessageBox.Show is working i.e whenever the text is inserted in database. If the inputed text is there in database it will return in MessageBox.Show otherwise else query is fired which show No "+ TextBox1.Text+" exist in database

Comment: "localhost" on a dev machine is not a server environment.

Comment: Actually i am testing that my database value is retrieved or not on query fired.If i removed i don't come to know that the written query is going inside database or not

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to see what columns are returned from the SQL table:

> select * from tblfiles5

Then you can use `mdr["Column1"].ToString()`, eg:

```
string link = "<audio controls> <Source src= "+ mdr["Column1"].ToString() + " type =audio/wav ></audio>";
```

Comment: Not working as i change my sql query to select voicename,id from tblfiles5 where voicename='" + TextBox1.Text + "'",con  and  string link = "<audio controls> <Source src= "+ mdr["voicename"].ToString() + " type =audio/wav ></audio>";

Answer (score 0):

First, **make sure that the audio file is uploaded on your server**.

Then the value of `voicename` at table `tblfiles5` is **just file name**.

And **You should use div at Literal1**. It means **HtmlGenericControl** component. Why you use Literal1.Text?

```
using (connection)
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
          "select voicename from tblfiles5 where voicename='" + TextBox1.Text + "'",
          connection);
        connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                    string link = "<audio controls> <Source src='"+ 
                    reader.GetString(0) + "' type ='audio/wav' ></audio>";
                    Literal1.InnerHtml = link;
            }
        }
        else
        {
                    MessageBox.Show("No "+ TextBox1.Text+" exist in database");
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
```

At the aspx file :

```
          <div id="Literal1" runat="server">
          </div>
```

Comment: you should give more info, what is the meaning of not working? 
Actually, your question not so clear. What is Literal1?  TextBox? Label? It should updated on postback, and changed after button clicked. If you use div component you need InnerHtml instead of Literal1.Text

Comment: I updated the question, i hope it will make you clear

Comment: @JeremyThompson no I don't